# How do I use getNodeSet (XML package) within a function?

Tags: r, xml, function, xpath

I am trying to develop a script to extract information from xml files. After parsing the XML file I use

```
idNodes <- getNodeSet(doc, "//compound[@identifier='101.37_1176.0998m/z']")
```

to subset a particular part of the document and then extract information I need using lines such as

```
subject <- sapply(idNodes, xpathSApply, path = './condition/sample', function(x) xmlAttrs(x)['name'])
```

My xml file has hundreds of identifiers of the type 101.37_1176.0998m/z
It is not possible to load all of the identifiers at once so I need iterate through the file by using getNodeSet followed by data extraction

My script works fine if I enter the identifier manually, i.e.

```
idNodes <- getNodeSet(doc, "//compound[@identifier='101.37_1176.0998m/z']")
```

but I would like to write a function so I can use do.call to pass the function a list of identifiers.

I have tried

```
xtract <- function(id){
idNodes <- getNodeSet(doc, "//compound[@identifier='id']")}
```

but when I use this function, i.e.

```
xtract('102.91_1180.5732m/z')
```

or

```
compounds <- c("101.37_1176.0998m/z", "102.91_1180.5732m/z")
```

do.call("xtract", list(compounds))

it is clear that getNodeSet has not worked, i.e. there is no data to be extracted.
If I use

```
xtract(102.91_1180.5732m/z)
```

I get: Error: unexpected input in "xtract(102.91_"
Can anyone help resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function it should be

```
idNodes <- getNodeSet(doc, paste0("//compound[@identifier='",id,"']"))
```

then the following call will work

```
xtract('102.91_1180.5732m/z')
```

Comment: Thank You! This has worked great. N.B. just needed an extra ) at the end